# How to pass file name with Url in location.replace() method

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass file name as instance to url using any redirect page method .

```js
<script>
           function my function() {
               var x = document.getElementById("demo");
               location.replace("localhost:57168/Hoopweb_Viwer.aspx?scs=" +x);
           }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this which uses `window.location.replace` to create simulated redirect, as you did in your code. Notice that reserved characters in the URL, after the protocol and domain name, are URL encoded to avoid errors.

I added `http` to your URL, but you can change this to whatever protocol is appropriate:

```
<script>
           window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

               var x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
               x = encodeURI("http://localhost:57168/Hoopweb_Viwer.aspx?scs=" +x);
               location.replace(x);
           });
 </script>
```